# open tty from multiple processes simultaneously possible?

Tags: c, linux, concurrency, serial-port, tty

I have to ensure that a tty device on linux is only accessible from one instance at once.
To do so, I have implemented a `flock()` function.
However, in my tests I wasnt able to open the serial port from another process at the same time even without the `flock()` logic.

Im now wondering if this is the normal behaviour in all cases so I can delete my `flock()` logic and rely on the blocking `open()` logic? Is it in any case possible to open a serial port from different instances simultaneously?

EDIT:

I have figured out that it is indeed possible to open the tty port multiple times simultaneously without `flock()` logic.
However, it seems, that the `open()` function is blocked due to the `flock()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, it is possible to open a serial device from more than one process simultaneously.

You can use the [`TIOCEXCL`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_tty.2.html) [`ioctl()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html) to get exclusive access:

```
if (!ioctl(fd, TIOCEXCL)) {
    /* Any further open() on the tty
       that is currently open on descriptor fd
       will fail with errno == EBUSY
       (except for the administrator, with the 
        CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability) */
}
```

and to re-allow other `open()`s,

```
ioctl(fd, TIOCNXCL);
```

You'll need to include `<sys/ioctl.h>` for the function, and `<termios.h>` for the constants.

Many Linux serial libraries already do this. Some serial drivers may allow only one open at a time, too, so to determine the reason for the behaviour you are seeing, I'd need a lot more details (how you open the serial device, and the serial device driver used, in particular).

Personally -- and I do believe this is what most Linux serial libraries do --, I recommend you *try* the `ioctl(fd, TIOCEXCL)`, and *maybe* warn the user if it fails (it returns 0 if success, -1 otherwise); and, in all cases, use `ioctl(fd, TIOCNXCL); close(fd);` to close the tty.